# Regex match as many of strings as possible

Tags: regex, string, awk, grep

I don't know if this is possible or makes sense, but what I'm trying to do is `grep` or `awk` a file matching for multiple strings, but only showing the match that matches the most strings.

So I would have a file like:

```
cat,dog,apple,bark,chair
apple,chair,wall
cat,wall
phone,key,bark,nut
cat,dog,key
phone,dog,key
table,key,chair
```

I want to match a single line that includes the most of these strings: `cat|dog|table|key|wall`. Not necessarily having to include all of them, but whatever line matches the most, print it.

So for example, I would want it to display this output:

```
cat,dog,key
```

Since it is the line that includes most of the strings that are being searched for.

I've tried using:

```
cat filename \
|egrep -iE 'cat' \
|egrep -iE 'dog' \
|egrep -iE 'table' \
|egrep -iE 'key' \
|egrep -iE 'wall'
```

But it will only display lines that show ALL strings, I have also tried:

```
egrep -iE 'cat|dog|table|key|wall' filename
```

But that shows any line that matches any one of those strings.

Is regex possible of doing something like this?

Comment: This isn't possible using a regular expression, but you could write a simple AWK script to do it.

Comment: would `cat` match `catch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `awk`, and increment a counter for each word that matches. If the counter is higher than the highest count, save this line.

```
awk 'BEGIN {max = 0}
     { count=0;
       if (/\bcat\b/) count++;
       if (/\bdog\b/) count++;
       ...
       if (count > max) { saved = $0; max = count; }
     }
    END { print saved; }'
```

Comment: You can assign it in the `BEGIN` block

Comment: It actually worked adding at the end, I just forgot to space it from the ' Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, -v r='^(cat|dog|table|key|wall)$' '{c=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i~r)c++; if (c>max){max=c;most=$0}} END{print most}' file
cat,dog,key
```

#### How it works

- `-F,`

  This sets the field separator to a comma.
- `-v r='^(cat|dog|table|key|wall)$'`

  This sets the variable `r` to a regex matching your words of interest.  The regex begins with `^` and ends with `$`.  *This assures that only whole words are matched.*
- `c=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i~r)c++`

  This sets the variable `c` to the number of matches on the current line.
- `if (c>max){max=c;most=$0}`

  If the number of matches on the current line, `c`, exceeds the previous maximum, `max`, then update `max` and set `most` to the current line.
- `END{print most}`

  When we are done reading the file, print the line with the `most` matches.

Comment: Nice solution. Our two solutions will differ if a word is repeated: mine counts it once, this one counts it each time.

Answer (score 1):

To make the problem more interesting I created two input files:

InFile1 ...

```
cat|dog|table|key|wall
```

InFile2 ...

```
cat,dog,apple,bark,chair
apple,chair,wall
cat,wall phone,key,bark,nut
cat,dog,key
phone,dog,key
table,key,chair
```

Note that InFile2 differs from the original post
in that it contains two lines each with three matches.
Hence, there is a "tie" for first place and both are
reported.

This code ...

```
 awk -F, '{if (NR==FNR) r=$0; else {count=0
   for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) if ($j ~ r) count++
   a[FNR]=count" matching words in "$0
   if (max<count) max=count}}                     
   END{for (j=1;j<=FNR;j++) if (1==index(a[j],max)) print a[j]}'  \
$InFile1 $InFile2 >$OutFile
```

... produced this OutFile ...

```
3 matching words in cat,dog,key
3 matching words in table,key,dog,banana
```

Daniel B. Martin